# DocuSign Electronic Signature : On signature window getting error "This authentication mode is not supported: NONE"

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Docusign API v2. I have observed sometimes when the request does not have `<signatureProviderName>UniversalSignaturePen_ImageOnly</signatureProviderName>` in the recepients node the signer gets this error on signature "This authentication mode is not supported: NONE"
This is very account specific. For some accounts not providing signature provider also works.

I need to know if I should always send this option "UniversalSignaturePen_ImageOnly".
We want to use Electronic signatures.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set that attribute if the account is set up to use Advanced and/or Qualified Signatures. This is also known within DocuSign as the SBS ("Standards Based Signatures") feature.

I'm 99% sure that you can also set `signatureProviderName` to `UniversalSignaturePen_ImageOnly` with no issues even if the account is not set for SBS signatures.